# EF config relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have thought:

```
 HasMany(d => d.Categories)
           .WithRequired()
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.RelatedEntityId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This piece of code mean that, `d have required at least one category`?

Comment: No, it means that the `Category` **related entity** is required (i.e. cannot be `null`).

Comment: Thx. So d.Categories is optional?

Comment: It's the *many* part of *one-to-many* relationship. And many means 0, 1 or more, so yes, it's optional (and cannot be required). In EF6, `Has/With` + `Required` / `Optional` are only for configuring the *one* side of the relationship.

Comment: So how I can configure that d.Categories should be required 1 or more?

Comment: You can't - see my previous comment.